# Efficient way of restoring ASP.Net site

Tags: asp.net, database, backup, restore

Can anyone recommend an efficient way of restoring asp.net sites, currently the steps I take are:

```
1) Unzip site backup
2) Edit web.config connection string to reflect my local SQLEXPRESS database
3) Restore Database in SQL studio 2008
4) Delete primary user in the database
5) Add the removed user in the Security tab and set him as the db owner
```

If anyone has any thoughts on reducing these steps or a different system any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make a backup of the existing site if you are restoring over a current version (in case changes have been made)
- Create any folders required and assign permissions
- Create the User/Application pools if this is a new machine

Otherwise seems reasonable to me?

Comment: Thanks Mark, an Issue I am having is that is it really necessary for steps 4 & 5 in my description, I don't get why I cannot just add an authorised user once and restore from there.

Comment: I also have this issue and just lived with it, just had a google and found this: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1063/sql-server-2000-database-restores-mapping-users-to-logins/  and this: http://surf11.com/entry/200/fixing-sql-server-users-after-backup-res  ...might be worth adding ot the restore process?